# Converting data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to assign concatenated string to my variable and I am getting the error  "Error converting data type varchar to datetime."

Please Can you help me solve this problem.

```
declare @msg Varchar(max)
set @msg = 'select' + 'File Date: ' + CAST(GetDate() AS VARCHAR(Max))  + ' data imported successfully'


EXEC DataImport
@PackageName = '',
@Status= 'Successful', 
@Message = @msg,
@FileName = 'test',
@PackageExecutionDate = 'test',
@Step = 'Import Flat Files'
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Your code does not make sense in either SQLite or MySQL.

Comment: There's no way a date string will grow beyond 4GB, so there's no reason to use `varchar(max)`. If you want control over the date string you should either use `CONVERT` with a style or `FORMAT` with a format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using C# code instead on converting directly on the SSIS Package using SQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT()`, which converts values automatically:

```
set @msg = concat('select', 'File Date: ', CAST(GetDate() AS VARCHAR(Max)), ' data imported successfully')
```

Neither of your original database tags support `getdate()` or `varchar(max)`, so you probably have other problems as well.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I have tried the CONCAT() it also did not work.